Retry HttpClient when didn't get a particular response
HttpClientBuilder custom = HttpClients.custom();
    custom.setSSLHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
    httpClient = custom
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
        .setRetryHandler(((exception, executionCount, httpContext) -> {
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            return responseCode != 601 && responseCode != 602 && executionCount <= 3;
        }))

I am trying to apply a custom retry function in Http Client .
dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version>
        </dependency>

Now, if a particular response code not achieved then retry again. How can I get the response status code??
I tried to do this:
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpContext.getAttribute("http.response");

You tried with what result? I don't see that code in your code snippet (it wouldn't even compile at the moment).

@M.Deinum I want to execute a Http Post through this httpClient.
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
exchangeConfig.getHeaders().forEach(httpPost::addHeader);
httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);

Please don't add additional code as comments, those are totally unreadable, edit your question in stead. I understand what you are trying but the question was what have you tried in your code for the retry, as that is what your question was about.

In addition the RetryHandler will only be called in case of exception not when there is a return value. So if the response did return but not with an exception it will be completed and not retried. Retry is only for exceptions.

Can I decide if it should retry or not by response status code? Like if response status code is 601 or 602 then it should not retry otherwise retry for at most 3 times?

Not without rewriting the HttpClient, as I stated it will only retry if there is an Exception, other then an IOException (check the code).

Can you please show the implementation so that it retries on response

No I cannot as you would need to rewrite the Apache HttpClient not sure if that is a rabbithole you want to go into. Instead just externalize the retry (with something like Spring Retry) to check either exception or the return code.
